# Javascript (variable.length == 48) when it should be 4

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation, echo

to summarize I have java/php displaying the word "good" in a div and java checking to see how many charictars is in "good" it should be 4 but my if statements says its == 48

so I have this java here that sends the users input (email address) to php on every key up to be validated. when the email meets requirements the php echoes "good". the java then gets the result(the php echo) and places it in the div email_feedback. this works fine

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#email_feedback').load( 'email_check.php').show();
 
 $('#email_input').keyup(function(){
  //username: is name of variable sent to php, form is name of form, username is name of input
  $.post('email_check.php', { email: form.email.value}, 
  function(result) {
   $('#email_feedback').html(result).show();
  });
  
 });
});
</script>
```

here is the relevant php here that echoes "good". which seems to work fine

```js
if ($email==NULL)
echo "please enter your email adress";
 
else if (($check_num_rows==1) && (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))){
echo "email is already registered with us";

 }

 
else if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
  echo "good";
 }
 else{
  echo 'invalid email';
 }
```

now here is the problem. I have this javasript that looks at email_feedback ( what php echoes)  and puts it in the variable "email_good" originally I had an if statement to check if "email_good" was == to "good" and if so echo "good" in the "check2" else echo bad, but it alsways echoed bad. so I tried (email_good.length == 4) 4 charicatars in good, it should work but after some trial and error I found out (email_good.length == 48).

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>

  function check_info1(){
 var email_good = document.getElementById('email_feedback').innerHTML;
 
  if(email_good.length == 48){
    document.getElementById("check2").innerHTML = "good";
 }
 else{
  document.getElementById("check2").innerHTML = "bad ";
 } 
 
  }
 

</script>
```

I guess the code I got now works but I don't like using stuff that gives odds results like this and I don't know why. so if anybody can give me some suggestions or ideas I would really appreciate it.

Comment: So "email_feedback" is the id of a `<textarea>`, right? Out of curiosity, what's in the `<textarea>` when it first appears on the page?

Comment: <div id="email_feedback"></div> nothing in it. but it does display "good" when a valid email is typed.

Comment: OK well it'd help a lot if you'd add `console.log(email_good)` so you could see what's really there.

Comment: Yes, if it says the length is 48, it definitely !== 'good'

Comment: like Pointy said, what's the contents of email_good?

Comment: when I echo email_good directly to check2 it says "good" like it should

Comment: also if I make the php echo "good1" instead of "good" then its equal to 49

Comment: Try this: `[].forEach.call(email_good, function(c, i) { console.log(i, c); })`

Comment: By the way, sending a POST to the server every time a `keyup` happens seems excessive.

Comment: If `email_feedback` is a `textarea`, you should be using `.val(result)` instead of `.html(result)`, and then `document.getElementById('email_feedback').value;` instead of `.innerHTML`.

Comment: not sure where to put it. got undefined

Comment: its not a text area. I been trying to figure this out now for 2 days. its really mind boggling

Comment: try this var email_good="good" and see what happens

Comment: or it could be that you might have 2 different div tags with same Id

Comment: when I put email_good="good" it returns false in if statment